# I am getting filepath as <_io.BufferedReader name='Filepath'> when I am browsing for a file using tkinter. I just want filepath

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

My code is in python tkinter, wherein I am trying to get filename in L6. But I am getting Filename as <_io.BufferedReader name='/Users/priya/Filename.txt'>. I just want path as /Users/priya/Filename.txt. As I am using tabbed windows, is there anything different I have to do

My code:

```
curdir = os.getcwd()
X_Train_Data=filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir=os.getcwd(),mode='rb',title='Select a file')
L6 = ttk.Label(labelFrame, text = "")
L6.grid(row = 1, column =2)
L6.config(text = X_Train_Data)
print(X_Train_Data)
```

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54968543/edit) your question to make it human-readable.

Comment: I did it. Can you please help